# How to show <img> tag inside the <p> tag

Tags: html, ionic-framework

I am building an app with Ionic, in which some codes are associated with some images, Now, in my post, which are from database, contains any of those codes, replace the particular code with the respective image in the `<p>` tag.

For example: in my post if (#mountain#) is found then the respective image associated with (#mountain#) is shown instead of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible for you to add a CSS class/ID to the `<p>` tags?

Then you could add a class to the tag for each post with the keyword you are using and then use a CSS background image to show the correct image for that post.

So if you add a class to your `<p class="MyClass">` you can then target an image/ div inside of there with CSS.

An easier way for you may be to add a class to the image tag, so `<p class="MyClass">`

Then you can update the src attribute of the image using CSS as follows:

`.MyClass{
    content:url("http://YOURIMAGE.jpg");
}`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I can use css class/id. Also my post is having simple text also with those codes for images. Can you explain it more.

Comment: Hi Ruchi, I added an example for you, hopefully this helps

Comment: hey, I am having multiple tags, i.e., if my post is having " this is a (#mountain#) image and a (#building#) image. Now my result would be: this is a //image of mountain// image and a //image of building// image. Now if I am using class then how dynamic switching of images in <p> tag is possible